# Does outlook web add-in of Exchange 2013 work on Outlook 2013 desktop client?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

As per this link, https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets?product=outlook&version=v1.5 Outlook Web add-ins work on `Outlook 2013` desktop client and they also work on `Outlook Web App (Exchange 2013 On-Premise)`.

Is it possible to get the add-in working on Outlook 2013 desktop client which has an email from the Exchange 2013 setup.

Comment: what does this have to do with programming...

Comment: The add-ins team recommends that I post any questions related to add-ins here, you can see their comments here https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for add-ins in Outlook 2013 to work on e-mails from Exchange 2013 On-Premise. However, the latest version of Outlook 2013 supports all our API's up to Requirement Set 1.4, whereas Exchange 2013 supports up to Requirement Set 1.1. Thus, if the APIs you need are supported by 1.1 and below, your add-ins should be compatible in both the desktop and web clients. If you are using APIs supported by Requirement Sets higher than 1.1, they won't work in the web client.

Comment: Is there a link/document which specifies which specific/minimum version of the Outlook 2013 client supports which Mailbox version?

Also since what update are add-ins available in Exchange 2013 on-premise setup?

When I installed Exchange 2013, I couldn't add the add-in, but when I upgraded to CU17, I could see it working.

Comment: There is no link that specifies exact client versions. We use requirement sets to ensure add-ins won't activate in clients they aren't supposed to. Could you share the additional value adding the build numbers to the requirement sets would have in your scenario? Read and Compose add-ins would be available in Exchange 2013 SP1.